# Find the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A,B,AB-I$ are invertible.   What is the inverse of $A-B^{-1}$ ?    I guessed some matrices but they don't work.  Is there a systematic way to figure this out without guessing?

Comment: $I=BB^{-1}$ now what is $AB-I$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J$ be the inverse of $AB-I$, so we have $ (AB-I)J=J(AB-I)=I$. After expanding this, we get $ABJ-J=JAB-J=I$. Now
$$
(A-B^{-1})(B J)=ABJ-J=I
$$
so $BJ$ is the right inverse. It's up to you to find the left inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\left(AB-I\right)B^{-1} = A-B^{-1}.$$

Now use that $AB-I$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Since $AB-I$ is invertible, there exists an $X$ such that $(AB-I)X=I$.

Note that $(A-B^{-1})B=AB-I$. Hence $(A-B^{-1})BX=I$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$(AB-I)=(A-B^{-1})B$.

(By "taking out $B$).